# dynamic add of attributes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

Suppose I have to display a corporative diagram, so I have different components, `corp`, `department`, `employee`.

Instead of doing all in HTML part of `corp` or `department` HTML, like this ...

```html
<corp>
    <department [...]>
        <employee name="John" isChief sex="m" picture="/john.jpg" />
        <employee name="Lucie" sex="f" picture="/lju.jpg" />
    </department>
</corp>
```

... I would like to have a dynamic list of employee controls instead in `TS` part of the `department` component

```js
employees: [
 { name: John, isChief: true, sex: m, picture: '/john.jpg'},
 { name: Lucie, sex: f, picture: '/lju.jpg'}
]
```

and from that one in TS to generate a list of `employee` components in the `department`.html component.

**Important:** I stress I would like to use a list of employee *components*, and not treat directly the employees *business objects* in the `department` component: the logic to display an Employee business object should be kept in the `Employee` dedicated component, just the properties of each employee would be cool to keep in the *logic* (`ts`) part of department component, not the *graphic* (`html`) one....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What you want is passing each Employees contained in Department.ts to their child Employee component right ?

Comment: I've to be frank, I'm not quite sure what you want still. If you create an employee component, of course you can dynamically render them with ease, by at least providing an @Input decorator and iterating through a list of employees and add the corresponding source file for images. But this looks like you haven't quite understood the basics of Angular (or even javascript for that matter)

Comment: the question is, in fact, how to dynamically add child components with different kind of options to the parent component

Comment: @SebastienServouze initially I asked about how to create a list of employee **components**, rather than a list of Employee **(business)objects** and use them in html

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to do this?

```html
<corp>
    <department [...]>
        <employee *ngFor="let employee of employees" 
                  name="{{employee.name}}" 
                  [isChief]="employee.isChief ?? false" 
                  sex="{{employee.sex}}" 
                  picture="{{employee.picture}}" />
    </department>
</corp>
```

The *ngFor loop will create as many employee elements as you have items in the employees array.

You have to modify your array though as follows:

```js
employees: {name: string, sex: "m"|"f", picture: string, isChief?: boolean}[] = [
 { name: John, isChief: true, sex: m, picture: '/john.jpg'},
 { name: Lucie, sex: f, picture: '/lju.jpg'}
]
```

Comment: your code will fail probably, cause `isChief` is missing from the second object... and I don't want to add the full list of options to each object that could be too long

Comment: You could easily fix that with `employee.isChief ?? false` so that when isChief is null or undefined, it will be replaced by false. [nullish coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing)

Comment: to add (or not) an attribute use the way: `[attr.name_of_attribute]="condition?true:null"`. It's important the "null" if we don't want add the attribute. Some looks like the attribute disabled of html

Comment: @Eliseo you should use `[attr.name_of_attribute]` on existing elements, however `<employee>` is a custom element. In the component of the custom element an `@Input` variable should be defined with the same name, in this case `isChief`. That way you can use `<employee [isChief]="..." ...>` instead of `[attr.*]`.

Comment: should we prefer `[name] = "employee.name"` rather than `name="{{employee.name}}"` ?

Comment: @DFSFOT, you can use a `@Input` or inject in constructor `@Optional() @Attribute('isChief') private isChief` if only want to know if you has an [attribute](https://angular.io/api/core/Attribute) in a component

Comment: @serge first option is actually cleaner, as it helps your IDE recognizing it's a directive. Both are okay though if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Eliseo I didn't know about @Attribute, it sounds pretty neat but I personally wouldn't ever use it due to it sort of going against the HTML logic. Empty attributes are converted to `attr=""` by your browser and I'd rather have a clearer picture of what's going on.